# Vue3 defineAsyncComponent and mini-css-extract-plugin gives WARNING in chunk Conflicting order

Tags: vue.js, webpack

When I use this code

`return defineAsyncComponent(() => import("screens/" + screenName + ".vue"))`

in my Vue app, where `screenName` can be any string.
I get the WARNING in chunk Conflicting order error in my Webpack 5.

I understand this happens because of order of components but what about dynamic components names how you can predict order for them?
Is it possible to resolve this error?